# Electron / Chrome: CSP connect-src not working - Security issue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, electron

I am building an electron client app which finds a server on the local network and then connects to this server with socket.io. I'd like to secure the client by preventing it to connect to others servers than my own using CSP. Funny thing is: Though Chrome throws a CSP violation, it still connects.

Here are the important parts of my code:

**main.js**

```
function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1200,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
      nodeIntegration: false,
      enableRemoteModule: false,
      contextIsolation: true,
      sandbox: false,
    },
  });

  mainWindow.loadFile("src/index.html");
}
```

**preload.js**

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require("electron");
const io = require("socket.io-client");

process.once("loaded", () => {
  ipcRenderer.on("connectSocket", (event, data) => {
    connectSocket(data);
  });
});

function connectSocket(ip) {
  const socket = io("http://" + ip + ":3000");

  socket.on("connect", () => {
    console.log("connected");
  });

}
```

**index.html meta tags**

```
<meta
  http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
  content=" default-src 'self'; connect-src https://example.com"
/>
<meta
  http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy"
  content="default-src 'self'; connect-src https://example.com"
/>
```

So if the server is discovered at 192.168.178.99 (client at 192.168.178.11) and I pass this from my main process to the preloader to the connectSocket function, Chrome/Electron throws a CSP violation such as:

```
websocket.js:124 Refused to connect to 'ws://192.168.178.99:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=hrNlyFY6i7-S1fUTAAAK' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src https://example.com".
```

Which is correct. But then it connects anyways. Why is that? Shouldn't it only be able to connect to https://example.com?

At least it says so in the documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/connect-src

This is on Chrome 83.0.4103.104, Electron 9.0.4, Node 12.14.1

Answer (score 0):

I think the [jsonp option in the Socket IO client](https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-api/index.html#new-Manager-url-options:%7E:text=transport.-,jsonp) explains this. Probably, the Socket IO Client detects that it cannot connect via Web Socket it automatically falls back to JSONP polling, which does not fall under connect-src.